# How to design a generic action class while keeping clean programming practices?

Tags: java, oop

The task at hand is to create a part of my Java web application which will allow me to easily execute small pieces of codes in a compositionnal manner. The task at hand is to allow the user to compose "actions" in any order. What I'm struggling with is passing parameters to my actions.

All starts with the action interface :

```
public interface Action {
    void resolve(Context context);
}
```

When the action is resolved, it's code is executed. The code can be anything : calling a method in Java, executing some Javascript...

Here, the "context" is the problem for me. Each action executes within a specific context. The idea is that the user that creates the action can specify which object to retrieve from the concept, for example the user that is resolving the current action, or other objects specified in the action's specific interface.

Example, let's look at this action :

```
public final class ActionScript implements Action {
    private final Parameters parameters;
    private final String methodName;
    private final ScriptsLibrary library;

    public ActionScript(ScriptsLibrary library, String methodName, Parameters parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
        this.library = library;
        this.methodName = methodName;    
    }

    @Override
    public void resolve(Context context) {
        try { 
            ((Invocable) library.getEngine()).invokeFunction(methodName, context);
        } catch (ScriptException | NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

It's a simple wrapper calling an action in Javascript using Nashorn. The parameters can be anything : objects with specific ids in the DB, int/String/boolean values configured by the user...

The code from an action can look like this :

```
public class DummyAction implements Action {
    @Override
    public void resolve(Context context) {
        User userExecutingTheAction = context.get("ExecutingUser");
        System.out.println("User " + userExecutingTheAction);
    }
}
```

So the action can retrieve runtime parameters (ex: user that executes the action...) and static parameters (created when the action is loaded - from a config file for instance), and all that from the concept. Besides, the user can for example specify references to object in the parameters that will be injected at runtime.

Actions can also be nested/decorated in order to achieve full compositionnality. For instance :

```
public class DummyWrapperAction implements Action {
    private final Action wrappedAction;
    public DummyWrapperAction(Action wrappedAction) {
        this.wrappedAction = wrappedAction;
    }

    @Override
    public void resolve(Context context) {
        System.out.println("Before");
        wrappedAction.resolve(context);
        System.out.println("After");
    }
}
```

This allows actions to be created easily :

```
// executes specific action 1 or specific action 2 based on a condition
Action myAction = new LoggingAction(new ConditionalAction(new Condition(3), new SpecificAction1(), new SpecificAction2()));
```

Knowing all this, what is the cleanest well to design the context class ? Should it be splitted into several elements ? The struggle is to inject everything needed to the class at runtime and be sure to not conflict with potential wrapped actions.

The Context basic implementation is responsible for :

- retrieving any object from the DB at runtime
- providing static parameters to the action developpers holding a transaction and giving
- it access to the user merging runtime and static concept, and this
  even in a wrapper (ex : if a parent action calls a child action, the
  user that executes the action must still be known so context should
  merge static child parameters and runtime parameters such as the
  user)

I feel it is doing too much. The design is affected by the Concept classes owning much responsabilities and their should be fragmented (right now every part of the application is linked to the concept). But how ?
Here's what I try to achieve in clean coding :

- the action interface should be kept simple (1 method max, with a
  reasonnable number of parameters)
- no usage of static mechanisms
- maximum immutability

In a true object-oriented way, and method oriented, how to solve this specific design problem ?

edit : removed public declarator in method in interface

edit 2 : I had a lot of interesting solutions, but the one that made the more sense to me was the one in which each action is parametrized with a specific kind of Context.
I reorganized things as such :

- Action interface has still only one method, to resolve the action with the context
- Static parameters of the actions, may they be DB or otherwise, are loaded when the action is created (user session)
- The context is just a facade for diverse operations (transaction ...) + specialized operations, like the user of the action

Comment: Could you simplify you question a little bit? As it stands its a little bit much to take in.

Comment: Of course ! 
The Action interface relies on the Context's object that does too much. Context provides a service to the action designers that can retrieve objects such as the user that executes the action. Should I break down context into bits ? Or is it something I miss in the general design ?

Comment: Ok now im starting to see your question more clearly. If its the `Context` object that is the problem, perhaps implementing the [ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html) interface instead of the `Action` interface. It has its own similar `Context` object and it appears to do the same thing as your `Action` listener?

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do, but I would concentrate on working out the client behaviour of this framework design first, rather than designing the framework itself. I'd write the code you want to invoke when the web page loads, and then work out what the various methods and objects look like. In my opinion, you have to solve how parameters work, and how actions return values to callers when you call "resolve"

Comment: My guess is you want asynchronous actions too: wait till first action is done, on success do this action, on failure do that action. What works best is (1) to have everything declarative, as data, composition of actions thereof, and (2) at run-time maintain that context. I have little experience, but BPEL might be what you are looking for. Or some Actor framework.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! Luke I checked but ChangeListener is not exactly what I'm looking for because I can't nest it.
Neville K you're right, I tried that approach at the begining but maybe I didn't focus enough on it ? I've made a prototype client side but what I have trouble with is shielding the client from the implementation details.
Joop Yes I agree with the idea, and basically (2) is hard to achieve. I don't know much about BPEL but I'll look more into it. 
Cheers to you.

Comment: You should strive to design a unified core API that `Context` will expose to all `Action`. Action-specific configurations and dependencies shall be provided through the constructor. It is ok for `Context` to have a wide-range API as long as `Context` is just a [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). Also, you will probably not be able to shield clients from concrete `Action` classes.

Comment: Thanks I actually redisgned my context as a facade in complement to Federico answers. Updating my post when I'll make significant progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd made the `Action` interface generic on its `Context`:

```
public interface Action<C extends Context> {

    void resolve(C context); // no need to use 'public' modifier here
                             // interface methods are always public
}
```

And then, `Context` could be either a marker interface, an interface that enforces a contract, or an abstract class with default method implementations:

```
public interface Context {

    User get(String user);

    // other default methods here
}
```

Then, you could do:

```
public class LogUserContext implements Context { 

    @Override
    public User get(String user) {
        // materialize user here
    }
}
```

And an `Action` that logs the user in could be:

```
public class LogUserAction implements Action<LogUserContext> {

     @Override
     public void resolve(LogUserContext context) {
         User user = context.get("theUser");
         // log the user in
     }
}
```

For a wrapped `Action`, I'd use a `WrapperContext` context:

```
public interface WrapperContext extends Context {

    Context getWrappedContext();
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class DummyWrappedContext implements WrapperContext {

    private final Context wrappedContext;

    public DummyWrapperContext(Context wrappedContext) {
        this.wrappedContext = wrappedContext;
    }

    @Override
    public Context getWrappedContext() {
        return this.wrappedContext;
    }

    // TODO other methods from Context, etc.
}
```

So now your `DummyWrapperAction` could be as follows:

```
public class DummyWrapperAction implements Action<WrapperContext> {

    private final Action wrappedAction;

    public DummyWrapperAction(Action wrappedAction) {
        this.wrappedAction = wrappedAction;
    }

    @Override
    public void resolve(WrapperContext context) {
        System.out.println("Before");
        Context wrappedContext = context.getWrappedContext();
        wrappedAction.resolve(wrappedContext);
        System.out.println("After");
    }
}
```

The idea is to also wrap contexts. You can enhance this design by allowing to chain or decorate contexts, and by using abstract classes that would be in charged of the tasks common to all contexts.

Comment: Very nice design ! I'm testing it right now in order to see if it fits my needs, I'll let you know what happens :). Many thanks for the insights !

Comment: Thanks ! It fits my design like a glove :) I didn't used the wrapped context cause it ended up all my contextes are similar anyway !

Answer (score 1):

Interpreter GoF pattern, interpreted tree can be externalized in some way. You can decorate any node, and will respond to your request nicely.
One more thing: action interface should have two methods at least if the representation is external (i.e. made by user): one to check for validity of the tree (e.g. a node requiring two children must have exactly those children there) and one for executing the tree.

Edit: here's an example

```
import java.util.*;

//context can be further complicated if you want visibility blocks (i.e.you need a stack of contexts)

class Context {
private Map<String, Object> variables;

Context() {
    variables = new HashMap<java.lang.String, Object>();
}

//this is to retrieve stuff from your context (variables)
Object getVariable(String name) { return variables.get(name); }

// put here the shared structs
void setVariable(String name, Object value) { variables.put(name, value); }
}


interface Action<T> {

void verify(Context ctx);

void execute(Context ctx);

T getData();

void setData(T t);

List<Action<?>> getChildren();

void addChild(Action<?> action);
}

// we offer some default impl, but we keep it abstract
// note on design: you can split (derive) this in Terminal / Non-terminal nodes (careful at the above interface)
// however, it's not in my objective to follow the pattern to the letter, but to explain how the things can be done
// plus, I need to kepp this short, it's long enough
abstract class BaseAction<T> implements Action<T> {
private List<Action<?>> children;
private T data;

public BaseAction() {
    children = new LinkedList<Action<?>>();
}

@Override
public void verify(Context ctx) {
    for(Action<?> a : children) {
        a.verify(ctx);
    }
}

@Override
public void execute(Context ctx) {
    for(Action<?> a : children) {
        a.execute(ctx);
    }
}

@Override
public T getData() {
    return data;
}

@Override
public void setData(T t) {
    this.data = t;
}

@Override
public List<Action<?>> getChildren() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(children);
}

@Override
public void addChild(Action<?> action) {
    children.add(action);
}
}

class BlockAction<T> extends BaseAction<T> {} //needs further refinement, including push/pop contexts if necessary

//let's implement your Action Script, some stuff left out.
// we suppose that the action produces some string
// that's a final node
final class ActionScript extends BaseAction<String>{
private final String library;
private final String methodName;
private final String aParameter;

public ActionScript(final String library, final String methodName, final String aParameter) {
    this.library = library;
    this.methodName = methodName;
    this.aParameter = aParameter;
}

@Override
public void verify(Context ctx) {
    if(!getChildren().isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Terminal node with children ?!?");
    }
}

@Override
public void execute(Context ctx) {
    //do whatever here (your code)
    String paramValue = (String) ctx.getVariable(aParameter);
    setData(library + "." + methodName + "(" + paramValue + ")");
}
}

// this can be further complicated, i.e. to have 2 subnodes, but for simplicity:
final class AssignmentAction<T> extends BaseAction<T> {
private String variableName;

public AssignmentAction(String variableName) {
    this.variableName = variableName;
}

@Override
public void verify(Context ctx) {
    if(getChildren().size() != 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("= node with %d children ?!?", getChildren().size()));
    }
    super.verify(ctx);
}

@Override
public void execute(Context ctx) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Action<T> child = (Action<T>) getChildren().get(0);
    child.execute(ctx);
    ctx.setVariable(variableName, child.getData());
}
}

public class IP {
public static void main(String []args) {
    Context ctx = new Context();
    ctx.setVariable("inputVar", "Hello world!");
    Action<String> root = new BlockAction<String>();
    root.addChild(new AssignmentAction<String>("var"));
    root.getChildren().get(0).addChild(new ActionScript("myLib", "foo", "inputVar"));

    root.verify(ctx);

    root.execute(ctx);

    System.out.println(ctx.getVariable("var"));
}
}
```

Hope it's clear now.

Comment: I've looked into the interpreter ; the examples are found are arithmetic like operations so not complex enoughs, I'll look more into it tomorow in order to see what can I get from more complexes examples. About the validation, why need another node ? Can't validation be made in the construction of the node ?

Comment: Yeap, I know that all examples are arithmetic (they offer a easy-to-grasp grammar). However if you're looking for a really extensible solution, that's the way you go.

Comment: In the end you will have a tree of actions.

Validation of the above tree, if user provides the input, should not happen on execute, unless you want to build something like a big try-catch over the entire execution. Validation should be done in the node.

Comment: Ok, I have added an example. Some notes: some stuff may worth their own terminal node (for instance, AssignmentAction should maybe have 2 nodes as children, one is VariableAction [Terminal], knowing how to resolve a variable, the other is a node that produces the result). However it's not in my scope. You can further refine the design and add any kind of nodes you like. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer ! I read it carefully and I had in mind a similar design with the hashmap for the context. What I was struggling with was handling all the transactions, getting data from the repository and passing context to children. However I didn't think about the parametrization which makes a lot of sense! I think I'll reuse some bits of this design too !